# Displaying locations based on post codes on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We tried to plot the locations based on post codes/address on google map using the google maps JS API V3. We need to first get longitude and latitudes for the post code/address and then plot the location on map. Because of this, each location plotting is counted as 2 requests and also there is a delay in showing up the locations on map.

My question is, is there a way in google maps API where in we can directly display the location on map without converting the postcode or address to longitude and latitude. Our application will have more than 100 users logging in and each user may have upto 1000 locations to show up. Even using the work license, the quota will exhaust quickly and delays.Any solution will be higly appreciated.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

Calling this url help:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={YOUR_POSTAL_CODE}
```

For more information on GeoCoding https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding

The more specific you set your address, the more specific the results...

ps... only your first question, the results... Not the displaying...

Answer (score 0):

GeoCoding is the correct way to do it. Here is an example with a address search input from Google:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Basically you just initialize the map on start and when the request to geocode the address returns the coordinates you set the map position. From what I can see this makes only one request to the Google Maps API.